# Convert json value to int in c++

Tags: c++, json

I'm reading a json value in c++ using

```
Json::Reader reader
```

and the value is stored in `Json::Value root`

This root contains "age" and "id" and I want to convert root["age"] to int.

I tried to convert it to string using .str() but could not get.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using jsoncpp?  It looks like you are based on the classes you are mentioning.  If so, it is easier than what others are suggesting since jsoncpp already has a builtin method on the Value class to convert it.

Answer (score 13):

In `jsoncpp` they provide helper methods on the `Json::Value` object.  You can merely call the `asInt()` method on the value to convert it.

```
int ageAsInt = root["age"].asInt()
```

Comment: I now get the error as std::runtime_error: Type is not convertible to int

Comment: An example of your JSON would be incredibly helpful in the question.  Also confirm what library you are using in your question so we can better answer.

Comment: My json content is:  {"age": "2", "date": "2010-12-07 09-40-38"}

I'm using  jsoncpp and json_utils

Comment: Okay, then you are getting the error because you are storing the value as a string in your json.  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Its working now.
I first converted this json value to string using .asString() and then used asInt().

Thanks!

Comment: @rocx It doesn't make sense to do `x.asString().asInt()`. std::string has no asInt() method.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
std::stoi( string )
```

Example taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "45";
    int myint = std::stoi(test);
    std::cout << myint << '\n';
}
```

Comment: my root["age"] returns json::value not a std::string
thats why I'm unable to use stoi()

Comment: Note that stoi raises exceptions, you might want to use atoi and then access the .c_str() of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot convert directly to int, first convert to string, then to int

```
                    string age = root["age"].asString();
                    int age2 = std::stoi(age);
```