# How to Convert Data in Json File to Values (double,int...)

Tags: c++, json, geojson, gdal

I am new to JSON files, so this might be a very silly error:

I have converted a Shape File into a GeoJson file Using GDAL in C++. The code I used is the one showed in the GDAL API for c++ ([Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)). I correctly read the shape file, and then I convert it to a JSON file with the following code

```
    char * json_poly = Polygon->exportToJson();
    Json::Value GeoJson;
    Json::Reader reader;
    reader.parse(json_poly,GeoJson);
```

Where Polygon is a GDAL object. Now GeoJson is a JSON:: VALUE which looks like this

```
   "coordinates" : 
    [
            [
                    [
                            586417.77972987387,
                            6884063.8642021669
                    ],
                    [
                            586655.1163914972,
                            6884198.7810712075
                    ],
                    [
                            586707.31919375062,
                            6884238.8010942638
                    ],
                    [
                            586703.2053746446,
                            6884258.7722300319
                    ],
                    [
                            586754.77872091066,
                            6884309.6043649064
                    ],
                    [
                            586832.7780266488,
                            6884413.5168099366
                    ]
```

But when I try to calculate the centroid with a simple for cycle, like in the following snippet

```
double x = 0 ; 
double y = 0 ; 
for( int i = 0 ; i < GeoJson["coordinates"][0].size() ; i++ )
{
    x +=  GeoJson["coordinates"][0][i][0];
    y +=  GeoJson["coordinates"][0][i][1];
}
x /=  GeoJson["coordinates"][0].size() ;
y /=  GeoJson["coordinates"][0].size() ;

cout << "The centroid is in " << x<< " , " << y << endl;
```

I get the following error

```
 no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘Json::Value’)
```

and if I try to cast the values to double  `double(GeoJson["coordinates"][0][i][0])` I get the following error

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘Json::Value’ to type ‘double’
```

How do I cast the values in order to operate an arithmetical operation with them ?

Comment: *How do I cast the values* -- I would be surprised if the library you're using relies on you casting things -- needing casts goes against the type-safety that C++ touts.  There are probably member functions that do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using the following libraries #include <gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h>
#include <gdal/ogr_geometry.h>
#include <json/config.h>
#include <json/json.h>

Comment: OK I found the answer to this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707898/convert-json-value-to-int-in-c. Thank you for pointing in the right direction @PaulMcKenzie.

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) explains under the topic "Getting Dataset Information"

```
double        adfGeoTransform[6];
printf("Driver: %s/%s\n", poDataset->GetDriver()->GetDescription(),
       poDataset->GetDriver()->GetMetadataItem( GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME ) );
printf("Size is %dx%dx%d\n",
       poDataset->GetRasterXSize(), poDataset->GetRasterYSize(),
       poDataset->GetRasterCount() );
if( poDataset->GetProjectionRef()  != NULL )
    printf( "Projection is `%s'\n", poDataset->GetProjectionRef() );
if( poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) == CE_None )
{
    printf( "Origin = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[3] );
    printf( "Pixel Size = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[5] );
}
```

`virtual CPLErr GetGeoTransform (double *padfTransform)` is documented here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716155258/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDataset.html)